# Show that if the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $a$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}{n}=a.$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $a$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}{n}=a.$

I am not trying to use the Stolz-Cesaro theorem.

What I am actually trying to see is if I can somehow use the idea of the proof of the theorem and apply it for the given problem.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists natural $N=N(\epsilon)$ s.t. $$n\ge N\Rightarrow |a_n-a|<\epsilon \iff a-\epsilon<a_n<a+\epsilon$$ The last inequality is true for all $n\ge N(\epsilon)$. Let's choose $k>N(\epsilon)$.

Then the inequality holds for $k,k+1,\dots,n$, so $$a-\epsilon<a_k<a+\epsilon\\a-\epsilon<a_{k+1}<a+\epsilon\\\vdots\\a-\epsilon<a_n<a+\epsilon$$ If we sum up these inequalities (can we though?), we get $$(n-k+1)(a-\epsilon)<a_k+a_{k+1}+\dots+a_n<(n-k+1)(a+\epsilon)$$ I am stuck here. Is the result I've arrived at somewhat helpful for what I'm trying to show?

Comment: Hint: Let $A_\varepsilon := \max_{k \le N(\varepsilon)} a_k$. Combining the bound you have with this, you can see that $\sum_{k \le n} a_k/n \le (n-N(\varepsilon) +1)(a+\varepsilon)/n + N(\varepsilon) A_\varepsilon/n.$ What happens to this upper bound as $n$ grows?

Comment: Let $s_n$ be the average of the first $n$ terms of $a_n$. Show $\lim \inf a_n \leq \lim \inf s_n \leq \lim \sup s_n \leq \lim \sup a_n$ and reach the conclusion by the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to summarize what you wrote in your post. Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N=N(\epsilon)$ such that if $i\ge N$, we have $|a_i-a|<\epsilon$. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^na_i = \sum_{i=1}^Na_i + \sum_{i=N+1}^na_i.
$$
Subtracting $na$, and dividing both sides by $n$ yields
$$
|a-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_i| \le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^N|a_i-a| + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=N+1}^n|a_i-a| < \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^N|a_i-a| + \epsilon.
$$
As $N$ is fixed (depending on $\epsilon$), and $|a_i-a|\le M$ for some $M>0$ (why?), we have
$$
|a-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_i| \le \frac{MN}{n} + \epsilon.
$$
If $n \ge MN/\epsilon$, then we see the right-hand side is at most $2\epsilon$, which is what we wanted to show.

---

The key is noticing that the first part of the sum coming from $\sum_{i=1}^Na_i$ is negligible after dividing by $n$ and sending $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This summation symbol really confuses me and makes it hard for me to follow your solution, idea and etc. We still haven't introduced it.

Comment: From what are you subtracting $na$ in the second step? What's the idea behind this?

Comment: @Trifon: It may be clearer to start from the average, rather than the bare sum as I do. Then we will subtract $a$ from both sides, rather than $na$. The summation symbol only means to take the sum of the corresponding terms.

Comment: @Trifon: the idea is to introduce the proposed limit. If $s_n$ is the average of the first $n$ terms of $\{a_i\}$, and $a_i\to a$, we want to show that $s_n\to a$. Equivalently we want to prove $|s_n-a|$ can be made as small as desired by taking $n$ sufficiently large. Notice that $|ns_n-na| = n|s_n-a|$, but it takes less space to write down $|ns_n-na|$, which is why I wrote it thus. It's not a conceptual thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Notice that you have just shown that
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=k}^n |a_j - a| < \frac{n-k+1}{n}\epsilon < \epsilon.$$
Therefore
$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n a_j - a\right| \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}|a_j - a| + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=k}^n |a_j - a| < \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}|a_j - a| + \epsilon.$$
To finish the proof, you just need to show how to obtain the estimate
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}|a_j - a| < \epsilon,$$
then you will be done!